# How to change the column's type from numeric to array in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have a column in a table with data type `Int32`. Is it possible to convert column into array data type `Array(Int32)`. If not what are the other ways, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The changing type of a column from *int* to *Array(int)* cannot be performed by [ALTER TABLE .. MODIFY COLUMN](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/alter/#alter_modify-column)-query because such typecasting is not allowed.

So you need to follow these steps:

1. add the new column with type *Array(int)*

```sql
ALTER TABLE test.test_004 ADD COLUMN `value_array` Array(int);

/* Test table preparation:
CREATE TABLE test.test_004
(
    `id` int,
    `value` int
)
ENGINE = MergeTree();

INSERT INTO test.test_004 VALUES (1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30), (4, 40);
*/
```

2. [update](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/alter/#alter-mutations) array-column value

```sql
ALTER TABLE test.test_004
UPDATE value_array = [value] WHERE 1

/* Result
┌─id─┬─value─┬─value_array─┐
│  1 │    10 │ [10]        │
│  2 │    20 │ [20]        │
│  3 │    30 │ [30]        │
│  4 │    40 │ [40]        │
└────┴───────┴─────────────┘
*/
```

3. **important**: depends on the count of rows in the table this operation can take much time to execute. To check the status of update (mutation) or find the reason of failing observe the *system.mutations*-table

```sql
SELECT *
FROM system.mutations
WHERE table = 'test_004'
```

4. when the mutation **be completed** the original column can be removed

```sql
ALTER TABLE test.test_004
DROP COLUMN value
```

*Remark*: assign the extra [ON CLUSTER](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/alter/)-clause for each query if the table is located on several servers.